# Format Preservation of FullSimplify on Indexed System of Autonomous Equations

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions

I currently have a large system [autonomous differential equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_%28mathematics%29).  I've indexed a more managable dummy system of identical form, using `Part` to reference each individual equation, so:

```
eqns = {c1' == -kf*c1 + kr*c2, c2 == kf*z1 - kr*z2 - kf*c2, c3' == kp*c2}
```

with *each* LHS denoted `cn'` where n ranges from 0 to 3 (or the # of equations).  Inputting `eqns[[1]]` yields:

```
c1' == -a kf + b kr
```

Whereas inputting `FullSimplify @ eqns[[1]]`yields `kf c1 + c1' == kr c2`.

Does anyone know a way to specify that the format ought be maintained, ie.

***`Some Input`*** which would isolate c1' in the `FullSimplify` term, or yield `c1' == kr c2 - kf c1`

This sounds petty and *is* in this dummy example, but isn't for larger systems.

Thank you in advance.

***Edit:***

I've spent awhile digging around online and in the help to no avail other than *possibly* changing my notation format, which would render my future use of NDSolve, where I hope to use the shorthand of `eqns`, problematic given Mathematica's understanding of prime notation for derivatives.  (Also, another complication in changing the LHS notation of `c1', ..., cn'` is in that each is an implicit (rather than explicit) function of (t) (*see my attached link in line 1)*, and so in NDSolve each `cn'` and `cn` must be appended with a `[t]` on the end at some point in the `NDSolve` function.

Comment: Does `Map[yourFunc, eqns, {2}]` fulfill your need? To preserve the format, you may apply your simplify function on LHS and RHS separately.

Comment: Just try the command and see what's output:) If I understand correctly, `yourFunc` can be `FullSimplify`. It will apply on both RHS and LHS, but won't make actually difference on LHS.

Comment: That does seem to accomplish what I'm going after in my dummy model.  Here's hoping I can successfully pull it off in my actual scenario.  Thanks, @Silvia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in [chat earlier](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9604987#9604987) here the two main issues:

First, to apply `FullSimplify` only on the RHS of each equation, many ways are possible. One very verbose way is to use replacement rules. The following example shows how to apply a function `FS` (you can replace this with `FullSimplify`) only on the RHS of equations having a `Derivative` as LHS:

```
eqns = {a'[t] == -k1f a[t] + k1r b[t], 
   b'[t] == k1f a[t] - k1r b[t] - k2f b[t], c'[t] == k2f b[t], 
   a[0] == a0, b[0] == 0, c[0] == 0};

eqns /. ((lhs : Derivative[1][_][t]) == rhs_) :> (lhs == FS[rhs])
```

Second, although the time $t$ does not appear explicitly in your pde (because it is autonomous), you still have to use it on symbols, which are dependent on the time. The example in the wiki-page you linked was $y'=(2-y)y$, but to use it with `NDSolve` you have to make the dependency explicit:

```
NDSolve[{y'[t] == (2 - y[t])*y[t], y[0] == 2}, y, {t, 0, 10}]
```